# Is 'Starting up datebase 'xxx' every few minutes normal in a SQL Server 2008 log?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've been asked to pick up DBA responsibilities on a development database.  In the SQL logs, I see

```
Date                  Source    Message
2/29/2012 10:32:01 AM spid56    Starting up database 'abc_init_empty'
2/29/2012 10:31:59 AM spid56    Starting up database 'abc_init_empty'
2/29/2012 10:31:55 AM spid56    Starting up database 'abc'
2/29/2012 10:30:48 AM spid56    Starting up database 'abc'
2/29/2012 10:32:01 AM spid56    Starting up database 'abc'
```

Is this normal? Or is the database unhappy that it keeps trying to start up the same database over and over?

Also, any references on what to read would be appreciated.  I tried Google but 'starting up database' just returns a bunch of useless junk.

Thanks

Comment: Check properties of the database, is autoclose turned on?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation that comes with SQL server, "SQL Server Books Online" (BOL), is actually quite comprehensive and fairly well indexed. The built-in search tool is acceptable, if not up to Google-like standards.

I'd guess that the database(s) might be marked with "autoclose", a foolish feature that BOL 2008 says will be removed in a future version. Might I suggest searching for Autoclose in BOL, for practise?